# R aggregate all possible combinations incl. "don't cares"

Tags: r, aggregate

Say we've got a dataframe with 3 columns representing 3 different cases, and each can be of state 0 or 1. A fourth column contains a measurement.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(round(runif(25)),
                 round(runif(25)),
                 round(runif(25)),
                 runif(25))
colnames(df) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "x")
head(df)

  V1 V2 V3         x
1  0  1  0 0.2201189
2  1  1  0 0.3798165
3  0  1  1 0.6127710

aggregate(df$x, by=list(df$V1, df$V2, df$V3), FUN=mean)

  Group.1 Group.2 Group.3         x
1       0       0       0 0.1028646
2       1       0       0 0.5081943
3       0       1       0 0.4828984
4       1       1       0 0.5197925
5       0       0       1 0.4571073
6       1       0       1 0.3219217
7       0       1       1 0.6127710
8       1       1       1 0.6029213
```

The aggregate function calculates the mean for all possible combinations. However, in my research I also need to know the outcome of combinations, where certain columns may have any state. For example, the mean of all observations with V1==1 & V2==1, regardless the contents of V3. The result should look like this, with the asterisk representing "don't care":

```
  Group.1 Group.2 Group.3         x
1       *       *       * 0.1234567 (this is the mean of all rows)
2       0       *       * 0.1234567
3       1       *       * 0.1234567
4       *       0       * 0.1224567
5       *       1       * 0.1234567
[ all other possible combinations follow, should be total of 27 rows ]
```

Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `ldply`-`ddply` method:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(list(.(V1,V2,V3),.(V1),.(V2),.()), function(y) ddply(df,y,summarise,x=mean(x)))
   V1 V2 V3         x  .id
1   0  0  0 0.1028646 <NA>
2   0  0  1 0.4571073 <NA>
3   0  1  0 0.4828984 <NA>
4   0  1  1 0.6127710 <NA>
5   1  0  0 0.5081943 <NA>
6   1  0  1 0.3219217 <NA>
7   1  1  0 0.5197925 <NA>
8   1  1  1 0.6029213 <NA>
9   0 NA NA 0.4436400 <NA>
10  1 NA NA 0.4639997 <NA>
11 NA  0 NA 0.4118793 <NA>
12 NA  1 NA 0.5362985 <NA>
13 NA NA NA 0.4566702 <NA>
```

Essentially you create a list of all your variable combinations you are interested in, and iterate over this with `ldply` and using `ddply` to perform the aggreation. The magic of plyr puts it all into a compact dataframe for you. All that remains is to remove the spurious `.id` column introduced by the grand mean (`.()`) and to replace the `NA`s in the groups with `"*"` if needed.

To get all combinations you can use `combn` and `lapply` to generate a list with the relevant combinations to plug into `ldply`:

```
all.combs <- unlist(lapply(0:3,combn,x=c("V1","V2","V3"),simplify=FALSE),recursive=FALSE)
ldply(all.combs, function(y) ddply(df,y,summarise,x=mean(x)))
    .id         x V1 V2 V3
1  <NA> 0.4566702 NA NA NA
2  <NA> 0.4436400  0 NA NA
3  <NA> 0.4639997  1 NA NA
4  <NA> 0.4118793 NA  0 NA
5  <NA> 0.5362985 NA  1 NA
6  <NA> 0.4738541 NA NA  0
7  <NA> 0.4380543 NA NA  1
8  <NA> 0.3862588  0  0 NA
9  <NA> 0.5153666  0  1 NA
10 <NA> 0.4235250  1  0 NA
11 <NA> 0.5530440  1  1 NA
12 <NA> 0.3878900  0 NA  0
13 <NA> 0.4882400  0 NA  1
14 <NA> 0.5120604  1 NA  0
15 <NA> 0.4022073  1 NA  1
16 <NA> 0.4502901 NA  0  0
17 <NA> 0.3820042 NA  0  1
18 <NA> 0.5013455 NA  1  0
19 <NA> 0.6062045 NA  1  1
20 <NA> 0.1028646  0  0  0
21 <NA> 0.4571073  0  0  1
22 <NA> 0.4828984  0  1  0
23 <NA> 0.6127710  0  1  1
24 <NA> 0.5081943  1  0  0
25 <NA> 0.3219217  1  0  1
26 <NA> 0.5197925  1  1  0
27 <NA> 0.6029213  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

(Nice reproducible code, btw, well-stated question.)

Perhaps the best way to attack this would be to create (and later
discard) another column indicating a grouping. Starting with your
data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(round(runif(25)),
                 round(runif(25)),
                 round(runif(25)),
                 runif(25))
colnames(df) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "x")
```

Let's first form a data.frame with all possibles, using a fourth
column to provide a unique group id.

```
allpossibles <- expand.grid(V1=unique(df$V1), V2=unique(df$V2), V3=unique(df$V3))
allpossibles$id <- 1:nrow(allpossibles)
head(allpossibles, n=3)
##    V1 V2 V3 id
##  1  0  1  0  1
##  2  1  1  0  2
##  3  0  0  0  3
```

With this data.frame, change the `id` for rows where you have desired
commonality. For instance, the following two combinations (1,1,0) and
(1,1,1) are identical as far as you care, so set the `id` variable to
be the same:

```
subset(allpossibles, V1==1 & V2==1)
##    V1 V2 V3 id
##  2  1  1  0  2
##  6  1  1  1  6
allpossibles$id[6] <- 2
```

From here, merge the two data.frames so that `id` is incorporated into
the original:

```
df2 <- merge(df, allpossibles, by=c('V1','V2','V3'))
head(df2, n=3)
##    V1 V2 V3         x id
##  1  0  0  0 0.1028646  3
##  2  0  0  1 0.1750527  7
##  3  0  0  1 0.3435165  7
```

From here, it's a simple matter of aggregating the data and remerging
with `allpossibles` (to regain `V1`, `V2`, and `V3`):

```
df3 <- aggregate(df2$x, by=list(df2$id), FUN=mean)
colnames(df3) <- c('id','x')
(df4 <- merge(allpossibles, df3, by='id'))
##    id V1 V2 V3         x
##  1  1  0  1  0 0.4828984
##  2  2  1  1  0 0.5530440
##  3  2  1  1  1 0.5530440
##  4  3  0  0  0 0.1028646
##  5  4  1  0  0 0.5081943
##  6  5  0  1  1 0.6127710
##  7  7  0  0  1 0.4571073
##  8  8  1  0  1 0.3219217
```

If you can accept the data with semi-duplicate rows (see rows 2 and 3
above), then just remove the `$id` column and have at it. If you must
unique-ify the rows, something like the following might work:

```
df5 <- do.call(rbind, by(df4, df4$id, function(ldf) {
    if (nrow(ldf) > 1) {
        uniqlen <- apply(ldf, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
        ldf[,which(uniqlen > 1)] <- NA
        ldf <- ldf[1,]
    }
    ldf
}))
df5 <- df5[, ! 'id' == names(df5)]
df5
##    V1 V2 V3         x
##  1  0  1  0 0.4828984
##  2  1  1 NA 0.5530440
##  3  0  0  0 0.1028646
##  4  1  0  0 0.5081943
##  5  0  1  1 0.6127710
##  7  0  0  1 0.4571073
##  8  1  0  1 0.3219217
```

(Slightly cleaner-looking code can be used if you replace
`do.call(rbind, by(` with `ddply(` using the `plyr` package. The
internal function and its results are the same. `ddply` in this case
is a little slower, but that could likely be improved with a better
internal function.)

Comment: Two BTWs: (1) if you used an asterisk instead of an `NA` in the `$V3` cell, the other numbers would be coerced to characters, probably not what you want; (2) though the `NA` here was silently coerced to the numeric `NA`, a more clear use should have been `NA_real_`, though the results in this case are identical. Try `identical(df6[2,'V3'], NA)` and `identical(df6[2,'V3'], NA_real_)` to see a difference.

Comment: Thanks, that works for special cases, but it requires manual editing (in your third code chunk). My research contains more than 3 columns, and I want to calculate **all** the combinations, to subsequently rank the results.

Comment: I take back my accolades for a well-stated question :-) The answer given by @James seems to be the most robust given your revised requirements.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me define a helper function to create all possible combinations of columns

```
allcomb<-function(x, addnone=T) {
    x<-do.call(c, lapply(length(v):1, function(n) combn(v,n,simplify=F)))
    if(addnone) x<-c(x,0)
    x
}
```

Now we can use this to aggregate over the different subsets

```
v<-names(df)[1:3]
vv<-allcomb(v)
dd<-lapply(vv, function(cols) aggregate(df$x, df[, cols, drop=F], mean))
```

This actually returns a list of data.frames for all the different combinations, to merge them all together, we can use `rbind.fill` from `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
dd<-do.call(rbind.fill, dd)
```

This actually leaves the "any" values as NA rather than "*". If want to turn those into asterisks (and consequently convert your group columns to strings rather than numeric values) you can do

```
dd[1:3]<-lapply(dd[1:3], function(x) {x[is.na(x)]<-"*";x})
```

which finally gives

```
   V1 V2 V3         x
1   0  0  0 0.1028646
2   1  0  0 0.5081943
3   0  1  0 0.4828984
4   1  1  0 0.5197925
5   0  0  1 0.4571073
6   1  0  1 0.3219217
7   0  1  1 0.6127710
8   1  1  1 0.6029213
9   0  0  * 0.3862588
10  1  0  * 0.4235250
11  0  1  * 0.5153666
12  1  1  * 0.5530440
13  0  *  0 0.3878900
14  1  *  0 0.5120604
15  0  *  1 0.4882400
16  1  *  1 0.4022073
17  *  0  0 0.4502901
18  *  1  0 0.5013455
19  *  0  1 0.3820042
20  *  1  1 0.6062045
21  0  *  * 0.4436400
22  1  *  * 0.4639997
23  *  0  * 0.4118793
24  *  1  * 0.5362985
25  *  *  0 0.4738541
26  *  *  1 0.4380543
27  *  *  * 0.4566702
```