# R aggregate and handle missing combinations

Tags: r

I have a data frame with my data x, and three different factors (subject, task and correct response).

```
 subj <- rep(c(1,2,3), times=4)
 task <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B")
 correct <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
 x <- runif(12)
 df <- data.frame(subj, task, correct, x)
```

I want to get the number of trials in each of the possible combination of these three factors (3 subjs * 2 tasks * 2 correct/incorrect = 12 combinations). Of course this is a bad example because I just have one trial of each combination but you get the picture. So I do:

```
 > aggregate(x~subj+task+correct, length, data=df)
    subj task correct x
 1     1    A       0 1
 2     2    A       0 1
 3     3    A       0 1
 4     1    B       0 1
 5     2    B       0 1
 6     3    B       0 1
 7     1    A       1 1
 8     2    A       1 1
 9     3    A       1 1
 10    1    B       1 1
 11    2    B       1 1
 12    3    B       1 1
```

But now say I have some missing combinations in my data:

```
 > newdf <- df[-2,]
```

Using the same aggregate function will not display all my possible combinations, just 11 out of the 12. I would like to get a length of 0 (or NA, or something like this) for my missing combinations.

Note: There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434437/r-aggregate-all-possible-combinations-incl-dont-cares) but it doesn't quite answer my problem, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `xtabs` from base:

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(~ subj + task + correct, data = newdf))

   subj task correct Freq
1     1    A       0    1
2     2    A       0    1
3     3    A       0    1
4     1    B       0    1
5     2    B       0    1
6     3    B       0    1
7     1    A       1    1
8     2    A       1    0
9     3    A       1    1
10    1    B       1    1
11    2    B       1    1
12    3    B       1    1
```

Even simpler, again in base from @Frank:

```
as.data.frame(table(newdf[1:3]))
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to (1) take the Cartesian product of your grouping columns, (2) merge that back with your data.frame and (3) perform your aggregation. In data.table, that looks like

```
library(data.table) # version 1.9.5+

setDT(newdf, key = c("subj","task","correct"))
newdf[CJ(subj, task, correct, unique=TRUE), .N, by=.EACHI]
```

which gives

```
    subj task correct N
 1:    1    A       0 1
 2:    1    A       1 1
 3:    1    B       0 1
 4:    1    B       1 1
 5:    2    A       0 1
 6:    2    A       1 0 # not NA
 7:    2    B       0 1
 8:    2    B       1 1
 9:    3    A       0 1
10:    3    A       1 1
11:    3    B       0 1
12:    3    B       1 1
```

`setDT` modifies `newdf` so that data.table syntax works with it. Setting the `key` sorts the table by those columns and prepares it for faster merging.

`CJ` takes the "Cross" or "Cartesian" product of its arguments. (`expand.grid`, seen in @nongkrong's answer, is the base R analogue.) The syntax `X[Y, j, by=.EACHI]` says: merge `X` and `Y`, and for each unique combination of merge columns, compute `j`. In this case, you were looking for `length`, which is the same as the number of rows; in data.table, `.N` is a shortcut to this number.

For this special case, of aggregating simply to count observations, I think the approach in @jeremycg's answer makes a lot more sense -- use functions designed specifically for frequency tabulation.

Answer (score 2):

A little trick with the [`sqldf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html):

```
library(sqldf)
newdf <- df[-2,]
combinations <- sqldf('select * 
                       from (select distinct subj from newdf) as a, 
                            (select distinct task from newdf) as b, 
                            (select distinct correct from newdf) as c')
sqldf('select c.*, count(d.x) as count_x 
       from combinations as c 
           left join newdf as d on c.subj=d.subj 
                          and c.task=d.task 
                          and c.correct=d.correct 
       group by c.subj, c.task, c.correct')
##    subj task correct count_x
## 1     1    A       0       1
## 2     1    A       1       1
## 3     1    B       0       1
## 4     1    B       1       1
## 5     2    A       0       1
## 6     2    A       1       0
## 7     2    B       0       1
## 8     2    B       1       1
## 9     3    A       0       1
## 10    3    A       1       1
## 11    3    B       0       1
## 12    3    B       1       1
```

The `sqldf` package allows you to manipulate data frames as if they were database tables, using SQL queries.

---

**Bonus**

If you'd like to create a "pivot table" with this data, with correct (1) and incorrect (1) as data labels, you can use the `reshape` package:

```
aggregate_df <- sqldf('select c.*, count(d.x) as count_x 
                       from combinations as c 
                           left join newdf as d on c.subj=d.subj 
                                               and c.task=d.task 
                                               and c.correct=d.correct 
                       group by c.subj, c.task, c.correct')
library(reshape)
md <- melt(aggregate_df, id=c('subj','task','correct'))
cast(md, subj+task~correct)
##   subj task 0 1
## 1    1    A 1 1
## 2    1    B 1 1
## 3    2    A 1 0
## 4    2    B 1 1
## 5    3    A 1 1
## 6    3    B 1 1
```